# Change camera tracking object

Tags: animation, camera, tracking

I am wondering how I could change the tracking object of the camera? Maybe something Similar to a key frame for what object the camera tracks to? I am using a camera object constraint for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tracking constraints have an *Influence* setting:

[image: tracking constraint showing influence setting]

Add one constraint for each object.  At frame 1 set both influence values to 0 and keyframe them both.  Now the camera will track neither object.

Anytime you want to switch from 1 object to the other, go to the frame just before you want to switch and set keyframes on the influence of both.  Advance to the next frame and swap the influence values so that the one that had 0 before now has 1 as its value.  Set keyframes.

However, this will cause a sudden jump.  If you want a slow transition, instead of the frame just before when you want the transition to finish, go back some frames and set keyframes on the current values.  Then Blender will "in-between" a gradual switch between the two.